# Function to calculate the product of several numbers

Tags: python

I had a function to calculate the product of several numbers, but it cannot pass the test part:

```
def mul(*numbers):
    product = 1
    for n in numbers:
        product = product * n
    return product

# Tests that pass
assert mul(5) == 5
assert mul(5, 6) == 30

# Tests that fail!
try:
  mul()
  assert false, "Expected a TypeError exception to be raised"
except TypeError:
  pass
```

If I modify the code like this:

```
def mul(x, y=1, *numbers):
    product = x*y
    for n in numbers:
        product = product * n
    return product
```

It works well. My question is why we need to write `product = x*y`?

Comment: Are you saying that your `mul` function is required to handle an empty call?  If so, just do `if len(numbers) == 0: return 1`, or whatever you expect the empty call to return.

Comment: @TimRoberts: I think they want the opposite; to have it die when called with no arguments.

Comment: Ah, I see.  So, `if not numbers:` /  `raise TypeError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*numbers if we use this statement then all the number we pass as arguments in function are present in `tuple numbers`

But in second case we you use this statement `x, y=1, *numbers` then first two parameter are not present in `numbers tuple`. So we have take their product explicitly and start taking product of next values

**Examples :**

```
def mul(*numbers): ... 
mul(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

then, numbers = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

```
def mul(x, y=1, *numbers): ... 
mul(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

then, numbers = (3, 4, 5)

Answer (score 3):

Your initial implementation of `mul()` will accept a call with no arguments.

So... Check that the `numbers` list isn't empty?

Answer (score 2):

"Why we need to write `product = x*y`?" Answer: You don't.

If you want the function to require at least one argument, and fail with a `TypeError` if it isn't passed, just accept a *single* non-defaulted, non-varargs argument. Conveniently, you can just accept it as the name `product` and avoid the initial value of `1` for `product` (at the expense of making the prototype a titch confusing):

```
def mul(product, *numbers):
    for n in numbers:
        product *= n
    return product
```

or just accept it with a different name and use it to initialize `product`:

```
def mul(firstnum, *numbers):
    product = firstnum
    for n in numbers:
        product *= n
    return product
```

Either way, with a non-defaulted first argument, you can't call the function with no arguments anymore, and it's no great increase in complexity to write it that way. Python does the work of checking the number of arguments for you and raising the `TypeError` if none are passed.